# Armv8 image stuck on booting process

Tags: boot, android-emulator

I can't make it to boot an armv8 image (API24, Nougat, Android 7.0) to boot successfully in Android emulator. The Emulator software was updated today to the latest version.

The first problem I can see in `adb logcat` is this:

```
01-01 00:01:28.730   857   857 I Zygote  : Preloading resources...
01-01 00:01:30.386  1040  1040 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-01 00:01:30.572  1040  1040 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xffff87ef99b001 in tid 1040 (main)
01-01 00:01:30.574   817   817 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1040 uid=0 gid=0 tid=1040
01-01 00:01:30.610   857   857 W Resources: Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080298 (android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_background_dark) that varies with configuration!!
01-01 00:01:31.065  1102  1102 E         : debuggerd: Unable to connect to activity manager (connect failed: No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:31.082  1102  1102 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 00:01:31.084  1102  1102 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_phone_arm64/generic_arm64:7.0/NYC/3245079:userdebug/test-keys'
01-01 00:01:31.084  1102  1102 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-01 00:01:31.084  1102  1102 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
01-01 00:01:31.085  1102  1102 F DEBUG   : pid: 1040, tid: 1040, name: main  >>> zygote64 <<<
01-01 00:01:31.086  1102  1102 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xffff87ef99b001
01-01 00:01:31.087  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x0   0000000071df8494  x1   0000000000000013  x2   0000000000000008  x3   0000000000000001
01-01 00:01:31.087  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x4   0000000000000004  x5   0000000071b05744  x6   0000000071b05748  x7   0000000000000000
01-01 00:01:31.087  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  00000000000ffffe  x11  00000000ffffffff
01-01 00:01:31.087  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000000000002a3c  x14  00000078a22b2c04  x15  0000000000000000
01-01 00:01:31.088  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x16  0000007fe6bc6f30  x17  0000000000000000  x18  00000000ffffffff  x19  0000000071df8494
01-01 00:01:31.088  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000000070605088  x22  0000000000000000  x23  0000000000000000
01-01 00:01:31.088  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x24  ffffff87ef99b001  x25  00000078a27f7ed8  x26  0000000070605088  x27  00000078a283d180
01-01 00:01:31.089  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     x28  0000028800000000  x29  0000007fe6bc6f20  x30  00000078a2728c40
01-01 00:01:31.089  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     sp   0000007fe6bc6d10  pc   00000078a272803c  pstate 0000000060000000
01-01 00:01:31.353  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :
01-01 00:01:31.353  1102  1102 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-01 00:01:31.355  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000000000054703c  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickResolutionTrampoline+2572)
01-01 00:01:31.355  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00000000000dae1c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_resolution_trampoline+92)
01-01 00:01:31.355  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00000000000d1c68  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
01-01 00:01:31.356  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00000000000de6b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+252)
01-01 00:01:31.356  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000000000028c2e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodE$
01-01 00:01:31.356  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00000000002852c0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameE$
01-01 00:01:31.357  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0000000000551bf0  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+356)
01-01 00:01:31.357  1102  1102 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000000000c4514  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
```

After that I am starting to see these problems:

```
01-01 00:01:36.467   857   857 I Zygote  : ...preloaded 114 resources in 7735ms.
01-01 00:01:36.747   857   857 I Zygote  : ...preloaded 41 resources in 280ms.
01-01 00:01:36.749   857   857 D libEGL  : Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
01-01 00:01:36.773   857   857 E libEGL  : load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
01-01 00:01:36.869   857   857 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-01 00:01:36.928   857   857 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-01 00:01:37.516   857   857 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-01 00:01:38.151   857   857 I Zygote  : Preloading shared libraries...
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
01-01 00:01:38.325   857   857 E Hyphenator:    ... 6 more
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-bn.hyb
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-bn.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
01-01 00:01:38.353   857   857 E Hyphenator:    ... 6 more
```

a bit later:

```
01-01 00:02:33.431  1137  1137 I Zygote  : System server process 1305 has been created
01-01 00:02:33.497  1137  1137 I Zygote  : Accepting command socket connections
01-01 00:02:34.153  1305  1305 I Zygote  : Process: zygote socket opened, supported ABIS: armeabi-v7a,armeabi
01-01 00:02:34.204  1305  1305 I InstallerConnection: connecting...
01-01 00:02:34.217   861   861 I         : new connection
01-01 00:02:34.461  1305  1305 I InstallerConnection: disconnecting...
01-01 00:02:34.462   861   861 E         : eof
01-01 00:02:34.462   861   861 E         : failed to read size
01-01 00:02:34.462   861   861 I         : closing connection
01-01 00:02:35.107  1305  1305 W SystemServer: System clock is before 1970; setting to 1970.
01-01 00:02:35.153  1305  1305 I SystemServer: Entered the Android system server!
01-01 00:02:35.184  1305  1305 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xffff80f5b1a001 in tid 1305 (system_server)
01-01 00:02:35.213   817   817 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=1305 uid=1000 gid=1000 tid=1305
01-01 00:02:35.231   817   817 E         : debuggerd: waitpid returned unexpected pid (0), committing murder-suicide
01-01 00:02:35.231   817   817 W         : debuggerd: pid 0 received signal 9
01-01 00:02:35.280   817   817 E         : debuggerd: killing target 1305
```

After 7 minutes of trying I get this:

```
01-01 00:07:23.083  2429  2429 I InstallerConnection: connecting...
01-01 00:07:23.085   861   861 I         : new connection
01-01 00:07:23.112  2429  2429 I SystemServiceManager: Starting com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$Lifecycle
01-01 00:07:23.255  2429  2429 I ActivityManager: Memory class: 48
01-01 00:07:23.271  2429  2449 I ServiceThread: Enabled StrictMode logging for ActivityManager looper.
01-01 00:07:23.291  2429  2450 I ServiceThread: Enabled StrictMode logging for android.ui looper.
01-01 00:07:24.241   861   861 E         : eof
01-01 00:07:24.242   861   861 E         : failed to read size
01-01 00:07:24.242   861   861 I         : closing connection
01-01 00:07:24.302  2281  2281 I Zygote  : Process 2429 exited due to signal (11)
01-01 00:07:24.302  2281  2281 E Zygote  : Exit zygote because system server (2429) has terminated
```

Then everything repeats again for hours and I never get to the launcher.

Basically, what happens is that, SystemServer crashes due to a SIGSEGV, so what can I do about it ? I have tried many armv8 images and none of them work, I tried on 2 different computers, with opengl in hardware and opengl in software.

What else can I try? I need to make it work to test an arm-64bit APK before I upload it to Google store.

Maybe the issue is in the hardware I am picking for the emulator? I am using Nexus 5 device.

Answer (score 3):

Y solved it!!! (after 2 days of work)
It is not an ideal solution, but it works. 
Apparently Google screw it with the emulators and the current version (1 May 2019) doesn't work with ARM8 images, so the solution is to downgrade the emulator software.

Here is the question that pointed me into the right direction:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120854/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator/49284378#49284378

And the emulator I used was this:
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-4266726.zip

No more SEGFAULTS with arm64 bit images.

Comment: This was my exact problem. I was stuck trying to load an emulator (it was taking hours), and downgrading the emulator worked for me. Now I see the UI.